# What is kernel-package? Why we need to install kernel-package? (or Why we have to use another kernel source from http://www.kernel.org)

Tags: system-installation, kernel

I have googled the first question but no obvious result appeared for beginners like me. So I gather two important question into a post so that other people can find. Please correct me if I misunderstand something.

---

According to [mannages.ubuntu](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/kernel-package.5.html)

> The kernel-package package use to automate the routine steps required
> to compile and install a different (custom) kernel.

So Why we need to install kernel-package? [ask.ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1355385/what-is-meant-by-the-ubuntu-kernel)

> There is a project, started and headed by Linus Torvalds, that maintains the source code for a kernel called the Linux kernel. This is what's distributed at kernel.org. **Note that this is not a kernel, it's source code** — Like a recipe for a cake but not a cake: To make a cake, you have to follow the recipe step by step, mix ingredients, bake; To make a kernel, you have to configure the source code for your computer and compile it.

Comment: Please specify, which kernel package you mean. For info on what a kernel is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(operating_system)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are there so many "linux-" kernel packages on my machine, and what do they all do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/266772/why-are-there-so-many-linux-kernel-packages-on-my-machine-and-what-do-they-a)

Comment: Also see here: [What are the differences between the Ubuntu shipped kernel and the upstream kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37147/what-are-the-differences-between-the-ubuntu-shipped-kernel-and-the-upstream-kern)

Comment: @Bruni I mean the definition of "kernel package", not a specific one

Comment: @ArturMeinild No, I mean the definition of "kernel package" - What does it ever mean?

Thanks for the reference link but for beginners like me, it's contain too much definition. i.e: "upstream kernels", "Source patches"... although explained very detail. I think it's better to use analogy.

Comment: OP is talking about a package named `kernel-package` not an actual package that is a kernel. These comments read like the Ubuntu version of who's on first.